# Wireless driver stops working after update on Dell Procision 5510

Tags: 14.04, dell, iwlwifi, secure-boot

I'm writing this in case someone else runs into it. I have a Dell Precision 5510 with Ubuntu 14.04 pre-installed. It came with a bunch of DKMS drivers installed by Dell, which worked through the first several updates.

For some reason, after a particular update, the `btusb-iwlwifi-intel8260-1.7` wireless driver stopped working.

I used the ethernet-to-USB-C adapater to connect and reinstall the package. While the driver was compiling, I received a prompt to telling me it wasn't compatible with UEFI secure boot. Why it was before, but wasn't now, I"m not sure.

Anyways, after disabling the secure boot, wifi is working again.

Answer (score 0):

You must have upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04. 16.04 enforces that all drivers are signed with a key. Your driver is not signed, so you came up with the proper/easiest solution. There are other solutions, but they're much more complicated.

Comment: No, I'm still at 14.04. The DKMS driver was installed from an official repo, as well.

Comment: In terminal, type: dkms status, post results here.